# Linux/Cydia "Packages" Indices parser

Tags: regex

currently I try to make a regex to parse a Packages file of a cydia repo. For this I need a regex which match's anything from a new Line with a word plus ":" until the same match's again.
Example:
http://pastebin.com/5nupT3g6
What I want (From the example above): Package: au.com.psychlaw.mailrules
At the moment I have this:
`(?!\n)\S*:(.*|[\n\r])(?:(?!\n)\S*:*)`
But this not work when I have something like line 63 to 76.
I need this for javascript/node. I have no plan and there are no parser or I simply find no of them.
For testing I use https://regex101.com/

I hope somebody can help me.
~Nils

## EDIT: Maybe this ?:

`(?!\n)\S*:[\s\S]+?(?=(?:\n)\S*:|$)`

Comment: Please post a short excerpt of your example. Something like "word1:\n//stuffword1 //more irrelevant stuff\nword2://stuff\nword2" only what you want, and readable (don't write the' \n's, hit return...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
(^|\n)[\w-]+:(.*\n)+?(?=([\w-]+:|$))
```

Remember to turn on multiline matching! In regex101 that's in the flag to the right.

Breakdown:

1. `^|\n` We start either with a newline or beginning of the string.
2. `[\w-]+:` Next is the word which can contain letter or a '-', followed by ':'.
3. `(.*\n)+?` Now gobble up lines, but in a non-greedy manner so (4.) will stop us on first match.
4. `(?=([\w-]+:|$))` Look ahead for the next regex start, or end of string. Since (3.) is non-greedy this won't eat up everything.

Comment: This is also a nice idea. But which is better your method or my method which i added as EDIT to my post ?

Comment: NM, yours works. Don't know 'better' is a good word here, both work. Maybe your use of `\S` for words instead of `[\w-]` incase you use more characters, though it could eat `:`.